# jqGrid filter representation object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way to get an object from jqGrid that represents the filter parameters that were applied to the current result set? If yes, is there a way to later apply this object to the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually read the `postData` param of the grid `grid.getGridParam('postData');`

it has a string property called `filters` which contains the current filter of the grid (it's a json text).

you can modify it and then apply it to the grid using `grid.setGridParam('postData', postData);`